# order products by association count belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Class Sale

```
belongs_to :product, :accessible => true
belongs_to :brand, :accessible => true

end

Class Product

has_many :sales
belongs_to :brand

end

Class Brands

has_many :products
  has_many :sales

end
```

How do i get the brands that have the most product sales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay with activerecord you can use [Calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html) but it will take 2 queries to accomplish it:

```
>> brands = Sale.count(:id, :include => :brand, :group=> 'sales.brand_id', :limit => 5)
  SQL (0.7ms)   SELECT count(DISTINCT `sales`.id) AS count_id, sales.brand_id AS sales_brand_id FROM `sales` LEFT OUTER JOIN `brands` ON `brands`.id = `sales`.brand_id GROUP BY sales.brand_id LIMIT 5
=> #<OrderedHash {967032312=>3, 1392881137=>1}>

>> brands_with_most_sales = Brand.find(brands.keys)
  Brand Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM `brands` WHERE (`brands`.`id` = 967032312) 
=> [#<Brand id: 967032312, title: "brand-x", created_at: "2009-11-19 02:46:48", updated_at: "2009-11-19 02:46:48">]
```

Otherwise you might want to write you own query using [`find_by_SQL`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002267)